# Trackwheel Click Event Issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am dealing with [KeywordFilterField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/KeywordFilterField.html) which is populated with the list of the countries. Now the problem i am facing is that when i click the particular country it should move to the next screen as I have written the pushScreen code in the `trackwheelClick` event after checking that `_keywordFilterField` is focusable or not, but this is not the case. The `Menu` opens when `trackwheelClick event` is fired, at the center of the screen, rather than moving onto the next screen.Can anybody have the idea why Menu dialog opens on the trackwheelclick event instead of going to the next screen.

See what i have done on trackwheel click event:

```
protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
        if (_keywordFilterField.isFocus()) {
            int index = _keywordFilterField.getSelectedIndex();
            ReadableList readableList = _keywordFilterField.getResultList();
            Object selectedCountry = readableList.getAt(index);
            String countryName=selectedCountry.toString();
            urlutf8Encoder=new URLUTF8Encoder();
            String newCountry=urlutf8Encoder.encode(countryName);
            pushToSearchResult(newCountry,countryName);//To Next SCreen
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But it looks like: [image]

Comment: What class are you adding the trackwheelClick override to?  Have you tried logging or a debugger, to make sure the trackwheelClick override you've written is actually getting called?

Comment: Sorry @MichaelDonohue i didn't got your point.Can u ls elaborate? And yes trackwheelClick event gets called perfectly fine in 6.0 but in 5.0 it creates problem.

Answer (score 1):

The trackwheelClick event returns a boolean that indicates whether the event is consumed.  Once an event is consumed, it stops propagating to other UI elements.  If you return true, the menu will stop appearing.

Comment: thankx @Michael for the reply, yes i have returned true when my condition gets satisfied.See i have included/updated my question.